# Updating Shopify Google attributes via the GraphQL API

Tags: graphql, shopify

I'm trying to upload new products to Shopify from my own database.  So far I've managed to upload the basic product information and images successfully, but I'm stuck on how to update the Google Merchant attributes.

Does anyone know how to add these programatically, e.g. 'Custom Product', 'Google product category', 'Age group' etc?

I can't find anything in the Shopify documentation, but it seems unlikely that everyone is just manually editing these attributes product-by-product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two interfaces available

1. first is [using CSV files to import and export products](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/products/import-export/using-csv) so to update Product Category field
2. second is [GraphQL Admin API](https://shopify.dev/api/admin-graphql/2023-01/mutations/productCreate#field-productinput-productcategory)

for example to update a product's category and return the product ID with the full name of the product [taxonomy](https://help.shopify.com/txt/product_taxonomy/en.txt) node, try to post a query similar to this below

```js
mutation {
  productUpdate(input: {id: "gid://shopify/Product/7543352230044", productCategory: { productTaxonomyNodeId: "gid://shopify/ProductTaxonomyNode/3" }}) {
    product {
      id
      productCategory {
        productTaxonomyNode {
          fullName
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> Consider Rest API does not have proper end-point for this